# How to fill recaptcha with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, automated-tests, casperjs

I want to write test with CasperJS. But the form has recaptcha.

[image]

```
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox" role="presentation"/>
</span>
```

How to fill this check-box?

Comment: If that would be easy captchas would be useless.

Comment: Thanks Roland. But I must create automated tests for some forms. But each form has recaptcha...

Comment: Remove the recaptcha during dev / testing.

Comment: imho, automated tests should not test simulated human-computer interaction.

Comment: Thanks guys. I enabled recaptcha for my account.

Answer (score 0):

i tried some keyboard event, tab and space to click that checkbox:

```
casper.then(function (){
  this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Tab);
  this.page.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Space);
});
```

it is interacting with the checkbox, but the picture puzzle comes up 100 times out of 100 times, so i think it knows i am not human. i hope it help u a little bit

Comment: Can you elaborate? You have to click somewhere before pressing Tab and Space, right?